# SQL Need people born in month with longest name

Tags: sql

I have a queston about SQL. I have to make a query that gives me:

The people that are born in the month with the longest name. (So, in September)

I am using apex.oracle.com, I have to use that database of my school.

When I directly look for people born in September it's not good. I need a query that gives the same results as when I didn't know that September is the month with the longest name.

I know this is a stupid question, but it's for school.

Sorry if my English is bad sometimes. I'm Dutch.

Hope you can help me :)

I have this so far but I don't know how to go further...

```
SELECT voornaam, tussenvoegsels, achternaam
, nvl(to_char(geb_datum, 'month'), 'onbekend')
FROM studenten
```

Comment: check this [group by](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) just add `group by to_char(geb_datum, 'month')`

Comment: Because this answer will likely involve a function to determine the length of a string value, and because these functions are different across different database products, can you please tag your question with the specific SQL database product you're using?

Comment: this is a great place to start  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`SELECT voornaam, tussenvoegsels, achternaam, geb_datum
 FROM studenten
 WHERE to_char(geb_datum, 'month') = 
      (SELECT to_char(geb_datum, 'month')
       FROM studenten
       WHERE LEN(to_char(geb_datum, 'month') =
           (SELECT MAX(len(to_char(geb_datum, 'month'))
           FROM MyTableName))`

There might still be some small errors in it but I don't have any db here to test it.

Small word of advice: Translate your column names in your question. Not everyone on SO happens to be Belgian like me and so understands the column names. ;)

Answer (score 0):

As written, the question really asks you to determine which month has the longest name.  This can be done in a number of ways, but they all require you to be able to get the length of the values in the MonthName column and the function that does that is different in different database products.  I'm guessing that you're using Oracle (from the presence of `NVL`), and Oracle uses `LENGTH`.

Oracle also uses a product-specific syntax for getting the "top" row.

Therefore, to get the month with the longest name, you'd do *something like* this (my apologies for working in English):

```
 SELECT MonthName FROM Months ORDER BY LENGTH(MonthName) DESC WHERE RowNum = 1
```

and you can incorporate this into a large SELECT statement:

```
 SELECT Name FROM Students WHERE MonthName =
    (SELECT MonthName FROM Months ORDER BY LENGTH(MonthName) DESC WHERE RowNum = 1)
```

This assumes

- you have a separate table of months to examine.
- that MonthName is a properly expressed Oracle function to extract the month from the birthdate.

If you don't have a months table, you would have to do this:

```
 SELECT Name FROM Students WHERE MonthName =
    (SELECT MonthName FROM Students ORDER BY LENGTH(MonthName) DESC WHERE RowNum = 1)
```